# Non-capturing groups

Tags: regex

What would be an example of where you would want to use a non-capturing group? Here:

```
(?:7|8|9)
```

Vs -

```
(7|8|9)
```

Vs -

```
[7-9]
```

Is it ever possible that you would have a non-capturing group that couldn't be substituted with a `[...]` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it ever possible that you would have a non-capturing group that couldn't be substituted with a [...] ?

Sure, when the substrings you want to match aren't individual characters, for example:

```
^(?:foo|bar)+$
```

That will match a string like `foobarbar`. Doing the same using a character set alone wouldn't be possible.

> ```
> (?:7|8|9)
> ```
>
> Vs -
>
> ```
> (7|8|9)
> ```

A capturing group should be used whenever you *need* to capture the text and use it later. For example, if you want to examine the match and extract the matched group, or if you want to backreference the matched group later in the pattern.

Otherwise, the capturing group serves no purpose and a non-capturing group should be used instead.

Using a capturing group when a non-capturing group would work just fine has 2 issues:

- It's computationally more expensive, since the regex engine has to keep track of the matched group (despite the fact that it doesn't need to)
- It makes the intent of the pattern harder to understand at a glance. When someone reading a regular expression sees a non-capturing group, they can be *sure* that the group is being used only for implementing a particular logic (like repetition or alternation), but that whatever gets matched doesn't have to be kept track of for later. In contrast, if a reader of a regular expression sees a *capturing* group, they will probably expect that the capturing group will be used later, and will have to keep that in mind while reading the rest of the pattern. If the captured group doesn't actually get used anywhere, it's unnecessary cognitive overhead.